# PHP exec() not calling .jar

Tags: java, php, jar, exec

A few weeks ago I was figuring out how to run a .jar from inside a PHP script. I was having some trouble, things were complicated by SELinux, but I finally got it figured out.

However, it seems I didn't get it quite figured out after all - PHP is being inconsistent. I have two jars, and PHP is calling one but not the other.

Here's the code:

```
    $command = "java -jar GA.jar ". $_SESSION['options']['GA']['popsize'] ." ". $_SESSION['options']['GA']['congens'] ." ". $filename;
    echo $command;

    $output = array();
    exec($command, $output);
    print_r($output);

    exec('java -jar testJava.jar 5', $output);
    print_r($output);
```

I have it print out `$command` so that I know that the command is being constructed properly.

Anyway, GA.jar is NOT being called, but testJava.jar IS. I can't figure out why this would be the case. Both work from the command line. Both are being called with syntax.

I thought it might have something to do with the permissions, but they seem to be the same:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache   apache     13723 Jul 12 13:45 GA.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache   apache       781 Jul 13 19:02 testJava.jar
```

I thought perhaps it had something to do with the permissions on the file `testfiles/PHPout`, but GA.jar only needs to read from it, and it should have access to do that;

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 189 Jul 16 15:46 testfiles/PHPout
```

In case you're wondering what the output actually is, `$output` contains the expected output from testJava.jar, but is completely empty from GA.jar.

What other factors could be involved in preventing PHP from calling GA.jar but allowing testJava.jar?

(For the record, this is on a machine running Redhat with an Apache server.)

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the parameters you are passing to GA.jar.  Try commenting out code to execute the second jar and simplify your code to run the first one

Comment: It's not the parameters - as I've said, the exact same command works from the command line.

Comment: Can you please try `$command = "java -jar GA.jar " . escapeshellarg($_SESSION['options']['GA']['popsize']) . " " . escapeshellarg($_SESSION['options']['GA']['congens']) . " " . escapeshellarg($filename) . " 2>&1"; exec($command, $output, $code); var_dump($command, $output, $code);` and post the output you get?

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't seem to be working - it seems it's just caused the java to hang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what the problem was. I was premature in asking my question, I hadn't done everything I should have to diagnose the issue. The .jar, rather early on, executes a bit of fortran code. For some reason, the ability to execute the fortran code properly is affected by which use executes the .jar - so when running from the command line, as my own user, it worked fine, but when running from PHP, as apache, it ran into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `2>&1` to the end of the command to redirect error output to the `$output` variable and see if you get anything.

Also try `system` or `passthru` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: It's not producing any error output. System and passthru do nothing.

Comment: @MattS Could you send me the jar file?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's something I'm working on for work, and while the .jar is entirely of my own making, there is copyright protected data that it needs to access to be able to run, and I wouldn't be able to send that to you.

Comment: @MattS well, good luck. I can't help much more than that then.